# How to avoid library multiple checks in waf?

Tags: c++, waf

I'm trying to use different modules (with independent wscript files) across several projects, so that modules can be developed in a one place and can be checked out in many places.

I have a project's top wscript like this:

```
def configure(cfg):
  ...
  cfg.recurse('a')
  cfg.recurse('b')
  ...
```

And wscript's in modules from subdirs '**./a**' and '**./b**':

```
def configure(cfg):
  ...
  cfg.check_cxx(lib='z')
  ...
```

So, is there a way to tell waf to check libz only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there isn't something built-in to do that.
I can just suggest workarounds :
 - get something you know will be defined by the check_cxx
   if "LIB_Z" not in cfg.env: cfg.check_cxx(...)
 - or add make check_cxx define something
   if cfg.get_define("HAVE_ZLIB") is not None: cfg.check_cxx(lib='z', define_name="HAVE_ZLIB")

I doubt any caching can be performed in methods such as check_cxx, they can do a lot of things and are controlled by keywords...